# Netbeans scanning symlinked directories

Tags: netbeans

I have many projects open in netbeans that have a symlink to a library folder inside their source code root.

Does netbeans scan the symlinked directory once, or once for each project?

I ask this because it takes a **very** long time for netbeans to scan my projects, and the biggest part of them is the library. Which in comparison is about 500% larger than any 1 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it scans it once for each project (better: for each symlink pointing to it).

You can add symlinks manually under project preferences -> Run Configuration -> Advanced -> Path Mapping. But I didn't have fully tested if that's a solution for not scanning symlinked directories twice…